# Save hearts with PlayerPrefs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am building a 2d asteroid shooter game in unity c#. What I need is saving the hearts of the player for the next level. So I just made the score save what I need now is heart saving. The score is saved for the next level, so it works like this, in first level you have for example at the end 3000 points and you go to the nesxt level, then it will start form 3000, but if you click on restart or if oyu quit you start from 0 and fro first level. That's how the score works the same needs to be with the hearts. So if you finish first level with 1 heart then you need to go to 2 with 1 heart. if you finish 2 with 3 hearts tn 3 with 3 hearts will be started , if ou click restart or if you quit then it will start form default. The hearts are images UI, I was thinking to do like the scor with player prefs but I am not sure how.

```
if (col.gameObject.tag == "AsteroidBig") {
            if (heart.enabled == true && heart1.enabled == true && heart2.enabled == true) {
                heart.enabled = false;
                Instantiate (explosion, col.transform.position, col.transform.rotation);
                Vector3 pos = new Vector3 (0f, 0f, 0f);
                Instantiate (player, pos, Quaternion.identity);
                Destroy (col.gameObject);
                Destroy (this.gameObject);
                Instantiate (medast[Random.Range(0,medast.Length)],col.transform.position,col.transform.rotation);
                Instantiate (medast[Random.Range(0,medast.Length)],col.transform.position,col.transform.rotation);
            } else if (heart1.enabled == true && heart2.enabled == true) {
                heart1.enabled = false;
                Instantiate (explosion, col.transform.position, col.transform.rotation);
                Vector3 pos = new Vector3 (0f, 0f, 0f);
                Instantiate (player, pos, Quaternion.identity);
                Destroy (col.gameObject);
                Destroy (this.gameObject);
                Instantiate (medast[Random.Range(0,medast.Length)],col.transform.position,col.transform.rotation);
                Instantiate (medast[Random.Range(0,medast.Length)],col.transform.position,col.transform.rotation);
            } else if (heart2.enabled == true) {
                heart2.enabled = false;
                Instantiate (explosion, col.transform.position, col.transform.rotation);
                Vector3 pos = new Vector3 (0f, 0f, 0f);
                Instantiate (player, pos, Quaternion.identity);
                Destroy (col.gameObject);
                Destroy (this.gameObject);
                Instantiate (medast[Random.Range(0,medast.Length)],col.transform.position,col.transform.rotation);
                Instantiate (medast[Random.Range(0,medast.Length)],col.transform.position,col.transform.rotation);
            } else if (heart.enabled == false && heart1.enabled == false && heart2.enabled == false) {
                Instantiate (explosion, col.transform.position, col.transform.rotation);
                Destroy (col.gameObject);
                Destroy (this.gameObject);
                Instantiate (medast[Random.Range(0,medast.Length)],col.transform.position,col.transform.rotation);
                Instantiate (medast[Random.Range(0,medast.Length)],col.transform.position,col.transform.rotation);
                GameOverPanel.SetActive (true);
            }
        }
```

An if statement with hearts looks like that, it is a bit messed up, but it is like this. If you touch the asteroid it checks if 3 hearts are on, one of them is seting to false, then if you have 2 hearts on, then another one is going to false, and so on, till you have no hearts and you loose. That is th logic of the collision. Please help to save this hearts, ask any question becaue I know it is messed up.

Comment: Why do you have the hearts as separate objects and not a collection? You could just add the objects to `List<HeartImage>() hearts`.  Your if statement would just be a check of the `hearts.Count` property, and you could instantiate the next level with that as the parameter for your hearts.

Comment: you are right, I should've thought about it but before now I didn't knw about list, but is there a way with my code, so that it can remain uncaged, somehow to save it?

Comment: Are you using SceneManager to load the new level? Or just resetting the current scene?

Comment: just application.loadlevel

Comment: Any reason you're not using SceneManager?  Application.LoadLevel is obsolete, and the transition isn't very difficult.

Comment: first time hearing about scenemanager

Comment: so your saying that if I will use scenemanager then I will be able to load the scene with the same hearts?

Comment: See my answer below, but if you don't want to recreate the object, SceneManager might be the easiest way. But my honest suggestion would be to refactor this if statement, put the hearts in the list and use static data to communicate between the scenes.  This way your scenes are also independent.

Comment: Your mega-if is... shocking...

Comment: I know........................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here, depending on what's easier for you

1) Create a static class
Static classes aren't reset when you load a new level, so you can store any information about your player there

```
public class GameData
{
    public static int NumberOfHearts = 3;
}
```

In your code you would then update `NumberOfHearts` to reflect how many hearts you have when you get touched by an asteroid. For example,

`GameData.NumberOfHearts--; //We just got touched by an asteroid`

2) Scene Manager (doesn't apply if you're using Application.LoadLevel())

You could create a GameObject for your player at the root of the scene.
Then when it's time to load your level, you would call
`SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(playerObject, "sceneName")`

See [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/229589/passing-parameters-between-scences.html) for more information about MoveGameObjectToScene.

In this case, the object would be carried over with any scripts and subobjects, so you would already have all the hearts in the next level.

Comment: but how do I updte the number of hearts?